# kali linux update error (sudo apt-get update)

Tags: kali-linux

I have some problems with my Kali Linux version. Please help me to solve it.  See error below‏‏

```
# sudo apt update
Hit:3 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease                      
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease [565 B]           
Err:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Get:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-experimental InRelease [562 B]
Err:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-experimental InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-bleeding-edge/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-experimental/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

Then follow wth sudo apt full-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The repos is not working right now, try this command

```bash
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(or if you dont know how to use vi use gedit or gnome-text-editor)
and the comment out the original repo like this

```
#deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

and add

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main contrib non-free
```

Then `sudo apt update` will work again.